# 'self' used before 'self.init' call or assignment to 'self'

Tags: swift, initialization

I have an init block and the code inside is giving me and error saying:

> 'self' used before 'self.init' call or assignment to 'self'

How can I fix this? The error is at `self.documentID = id`

```
type heimport UIKit
import Firebase
import Firestore
protocol DocumentSeriziable {
    init?(id: String, xdictionary:[String:Any])
}
class Content {
}
    struct employee {
        var name: String!
        var adress: String!
        var timeStamp: Date
        var documentID: String
        
        var dictionary:[String: Any] {
            return[
                "name":name!,
                "adress":adress!,
                "timeStamp":timeStamp,
                "documentID":documentID
            ]
        }
    }
    
    extension employee : DocumentSeriziable {
        init?(id: String, xdictionary dictionary: [String : Any]) { 
            self.documentID = id // ERROR
            guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
                  let documentID = dictionary["documentID"] as? String,
                  let adress = dictionary["adress"] as? String,
                  let timeStamp = dictionary["timeStamp"] as? Date else {
                return nil
                }
            self.init(name: name, adress: adress, timeStamp: timeStamp, documentID: documentID)
            
        }
    }
```

I tried making it a class but it didn't work

Comment: Why are you even using a `Dictionary[String:Any]`?  Firestore supports Codable. You can simply make your `Employee` struct conform to `Codable` and then use it directly with Firestore operations.

Comment: You can just delete the line that is causing you a problem. `documentID` will be assigned when you call the memberwise `init`

Comment: You are trying to assign a value to the property `documentID` twice, first directly by using `id` and then by calling the other init where you use a value from the dictionary. This makes your code inconsistent and unclear. You can fix the error by for instance moving `self.documentID = id` to the very end of the init but what would it mean, is it the right value that gets assigned to the property? You need to redesign how this init is implemented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an `init` in a  extension is executing `self` doesn't have a concrete value until you call a designated `init` on the type.

In other words, at the start of your `init`, Swift knows that you will have an`employee` but that thing, `self`, hasn't yet been created.  There is no thing in memory that you can set `documentId` on.

After you have called the memberwise initialiser for your type (the `self.init` that you call after the guard), then you have an actual thing you can interact with.

One solution would be to move the assignment of `self.documentID` to after the `init` call.  But, you don't even need to do that, since `documentID` will be assigned for you in the memberwise `init`.  Simply remove the offending line and you are good.

A couple of other notes:

- By convention, classes and structs should start with a capital (so `Employee` not `employee`)
- I would say that using a `Dictionary[String:Any]` is an anti-pattern. Firestore supports Codable. If you adopt that approach you can get rid of all of this.